# How to stop uiscrollview scrolling where user stopped touching the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView, and what I need, is that when the user stops dragging it, the scrollview stops scrolling to.

Sometimes it works, but sometimes, the scroll continues when the pression is released.

I tried a lot of things with the scrollView.tracking, or with delegate methods like scrollViewDidScroll, or scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, etc. But for the moment, I didn't found anything !

I also tried UIPageControl but I need my scroll view to stop every 50 pixel.

Thank you for your time and your help !

Answer (score 1):

You need to impelement this method `(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` the `decelerate` parameter means should scroll view stop immediately or not. Try to use `decelerationRate` property to set the needed rate.

Comment: Thank you a lot. But how can I pass NO to a delegate method ? For the moment. I added this line in this method : [self.scrollView setContentOffset:self.scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES]; / And it does the job. But I think your solution seems to be cleaner.

Comment: I've changed my answer - you just need to manage `decelerate` property of your scrollView. (set it to NO in your viewDidLoad method)

Comment: decelerating property is ReadOnly. So here is what I've done. I added the method -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView / And when this method is called, I set the scrollViewContentOffset to its own value. This blocks the decelerating and blocks the scrolling on the exact place the dragging stopped. Thank you a lot !

Comment: yeah it is really readonly...:( may be try to use decelerationRate?? Because your solution looks like a hack...there must be a way to do it normally.

Comment: I tried to set it to 0 but it stills scroll a little and I really want it to not scroll at all when the dragging is over. I think I will use my solution, but make it softer, I will have a list of points where the scroll can be stopped, and wherever the user stops dragging, the scrollview will scroll to the nearest point. Thank you for your time Stas !